# draw component into a container

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to draw a component onto a container on the event of tapping, it does seem to draw except its not visible on the container. This is the code for further clarification.

```
Ext.define("TapCheck.view.NewTap",{
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  fullscreen: true,
  id: 'tappy',
    initialize: function() {
      this.callParent(arguments);
      var padElement = Ext.get('tappy');
      padElement.on(['tap'],
      'onTouchPadEvent', this);
  },
  config: {
      flex: 1,
      margin: 10,
      layout: {
          type: 'vbox',
          pack: 'center',
          align: 'stretch'
      },
      items: [
          {
              html: 'Touch here!'
          }
      ]
      },
          onTouchPadEvent: function(e, target, options, eventController) {
                         var component = new Ext.draw.Component({
                                items: [{
                                  type: 'ellipse',
                                  cx: 100,
                                  cy: 100,
                                  rx: 40,
                                  ry: 25,
                                  fillStyle: 'blue'
                                }]
                              });
      console.log('X: ' + e.getPageX() + ' Y: ' + e.getPageY());
     Ext.getCmp('tappy').add([component]);
  }
});
```

Please let me know where I am wrong or can this be even done?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated some of your code. The biggest changes are:

- Removed `id` config. Do not use it often and especially when defining components.
- Inside the `initialize` & `onTouchPadEvent` function just reference the component with `this`.
- Creation of components with the `Ext.create` function.

Try this:

```
Ext.define("TapCheck.view.NewTap",{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    fullscreen: true,
    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.on('tap', me.onTouchPadEvent, this);
    },
    config: {
        flex: 1,
        margin: 10,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            pack: 'center',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            html: 'Touch here!'
        }]
    },
    onTouchPadEvent: function(e, target, options, eventController) {
        var component = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Component',{
            items: [{
                type: 'ellipse',
                cx: 100,
                cy: 100,
                rx: 40,
                ry: 25,
                fillStyle: 'blue'
            }]
        });
        console.log('X: ' + e.getPageX() + ' Y: ' + e.getPageY());
        this.add(component);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didnt work however, I tried more fiddling around and worked out that the layout of the container should be a type 'fit', inorder for the draw component to render.

Comment: If you are using a `VBOX` layout you need to specify a height for your child items ;)